# Using unity animations globaly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to code an end for a level in a simple game. A lot of things need to happen at slightly different times. The character needs to do a celebration. Text needs to pop up on screen. The camera needs to move to show off the win, and finally there needs to be a scene transition.

This all seems like a great thing to solve with an animation. All these things could come in and act on specific key-frames, at the end raising an event and ending the scene.

The problem is it looks like animations have to be attached to specific objects.  My camera, player, and the static global GameController are completely unrelated. In fact the global controller can't be related to anything.  Because of that my animations don't see all the objects and can't control them.  I am instead stuck writing synchronized animations, and code with a lot of  yield return new WaitForSeconds(...);.  I find this very difficult to manage, and seems like a lot of waste.  Is there any way I can use animations, or some other frame based tool to globally animate my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Unity's Timeline system. I believe this is exactly the sort of thing it was made for.